# Install "Yeogurt Generator" / NODE_ENV error

Tags: node.js, npm, yeoman-generator, yo, yeogurt

I'm trying to install "Yeogurt Generator"
https://github.com/larsonjj/generator-yeogurt

With the command: npm run build
I get the following error:

> sample@0.0.1 build C:\xxx\yeogurt
>   NODE_ENV=production npx gulp --production

Der Befehl "NODE_ENV" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sample@0.0.1 build: `NODE_ENV=production npx gulp --production`
npm ERR! Exit status 1

I'm using:
- Windows 10 Pro
- npm verion 6.10.2
- node version 12.8.0
- yo version 3.1.0

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the `build` script was written for linux.

For windows it should be:

```
SET NODE_ENV=production
npx gulp --production
```

Comment: with the command `npx gulp --production` I get the following error:
`Cannot find module 'gulp-cli'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Yarn\cache\npm-gulp-4.0.2-543651070fd0f6ab0a0650c6a3e6ff5a7cb09caa\bin\gulp.js`

Comment: Try to reinstall `gulp` either locally or globally (with `-g` flag).

Also try to clean yarn cache: `yarn cache clean`

Comment: I've installed gulp globally and clean the yarn cache, but always the same error !

Comment: Ok, I don't really know why this happens. One workaround that I can suggest is, instead of `npx`, run `node node_modules/.bin/gulp --production`

Comment: The next error after trying `node node_modules/.bin/gulp --production`
C:\laragon\www\yeogurt\node_modules\.bin\gulp:2
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
          ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:22)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:731:32)

Comment: For Info I'm not using the standard node and npm location, but a custom location under largagon\bin folder